# Deploy Google cloud Function on Github actions

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, github-actions

i have my code in a folder on my repo. The purpose it's to deploy the code (main.py) to Google cloud and sync my code. I have create a function and an account service on Google Cloud Platform. i've create also secrets for EMAIL AND PRIVATE KEY (account service) and a secret for the ID PROJECT. But i have an error:

Do you have a solution ?

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQCED.png)

[image: Workflow]

Answer (score 2):

The first thing to do would be to go to the actions and look at the build log and specifically at the failed step (which most likely is going to be function deploying). Look at the error, good chance it is going to tell you what exactly went wrong.

If I had to make an educated guess, I'd say your service account doesn't have enough permissions (mine was setup with two - Cloud Functions Developer role and Service Account User) or the way you deploy the function isn't correct. I see that you  are not exporting default credentials when you setup gcloud sdk, is there a reason for that?

Picture worth a thousand words - I've created a simple [repo](https://github.com/jabbson/cloud-function-test), where I have the most basic (default) python function that I deploy to GCF. Check it out, this should be enough to get you started.

**UPDATE:** 
In case I decide to delete the repo one day, I am going to include the build yaml in here as well:

```
# This is a basic workflow to help you get started with Actions
name: CI

# Controls when the action will run. 
on:
  # Triggers the workflow on push or pull request events but only for the main branch
  push:
    branches: [ main ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ main ]

  # Allows you to run this workflow manually from the Actions tab
  workflow_dispatch:

# A workflow run is made up of one or more jobs that can run sequentially or in parallel
jobs:
  # This workflow contains a single job called "build"
  build:
    # The type of runner that the job will run on
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    # Steps represent a sequence of tasks that will be executed as part of the job
    steps:
      # Checks-out your repository under $GITHUB_WORKSPACE, so your job can access it
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Set up gcloud Cloud SDK environment
        # You may pin to the exact commit or the version.
        # uses: google-github-actions/setup-gcloud@94337306dda8180d967a56932ceb4ddcf01edae7
        uses: google-github-actions/setup-gcloud@v0.2.0
        with:
          
          # Service account email address to use for authentication. This is required
          # for legacy .p12 keys but can be omitted for .json keys. This is usually of
          # the format <name>@<project-id>.iam.gserviceaccount.com.
          service_account_email: ${{ secrets.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL }} # optional
          
          # Service account key to use for authentication. This should be the JSON
          # formatted private key which can be exported from the Cloud Console. The
          # value can be raw or base64-encoded.
          service_account_key: ${{ secrets.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_KEY }} # optional
          
          # ID of the Google Cloud project. If provided, this will configure gcloud to
          # use this project ID by default for commands. Individual commands can still
          # override the project using the --project flag which takes precedence.
          project_id: ${{ secrets.PROJECT_ID }} # optional
          
          # Export the provided credentials as Google Default Application Credentials.
          # This will make the credentials available to later steps via the
          # GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable. Future steps that
          # consume Default Application Credentials will automatically detect and use
          # these credentials.
          export_default_credentials: true # optional



      # Runs a single command using the runners shell
      - name: Deploy the function
        run: gcloud functions deploy myfunc --trigger-http --runtime=python39
```

Comment: thx for the help !. I've got added the roles Cloud Functions Developer role and Service Account User on my service account. But can i use the serverless method for Google? it's working or not ? i'm a beginner on google cloud.

Comment: https://imgur.com/17GS13K My Github actions Logs. I don't know what secrets is in the wrong JSON format. :/

Comment: @Palmé secret should be the [json formatted key that you create for the service account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-account-keys#creating_service_account_keys)

Comment: it should be the content of the entire json file

Comment: thanks, i fixed the problem. However, can I use the YML serverless solution? with the --source option I cannot use the code from my main.py file on my repository. https://imgur.com/ou6T2Om